# How to delete NDB value by key

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want to delete the selected value from the database in ndb, I have the following html code:

Getting the Data in Rooms as:

Class Method:

```
all_rooms = Room.query().fetch()

template_values = {
    'logout_url': users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri),
    'rooms': all_rooms
}

template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('rooms.html')
self.response.write(template.render(template_values))
```

HTML:

```
{% for i in rooms %}
      <br/>
        <form action="/rooms" method="post">
           <input type="hidden" name="roomKey" value="{{ i.key }}"/>
          <input type="submit" value="Delete" name="button"/>
        </form>
    {{i.key}}
    Room Nummber:{{ i.roomNumber }}
    <br/>
{% endfor %}
```

Which OutPuts As Following:

> Key('Room', 4644337115725824) Room Nummber:10

I am passing the key to the delete method which is coming as:
Key('Room', 4644337115725824)

How should I retrieve key from it in order to delete the value Room Value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `i.key.urlsafe()`.  This will convert the key to a "url safe" string which is exactly where you plan to use it: in a url.

When you get the `roomKey` values back, you can convert them back from strings in urlsafe format to ndb Key objects by doing `ndb.Key(urlsafe=roomKey)` (see [this link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/keyclass#Constructors)).

BONUS TIP:  This would be extremely insecure code.  Okay if this app is just for you (after sign-in) but dangerous if for untrusted users.  Why?  Well, someone could mock your HTML with keys for any object of any type and then simulate clicking the delete button.  Your GAE-side code would blindly convert the urlsafe strings to keys and delete stuff.

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: How to make it safer?

Comment: Okay, harder, need to reinvent some wheels.  One way would be to put all the urlsafe key-strings in a comma-separated string "dsfsdf,sfsfsdf,sfdsf", then calculate the SHA-256 hash of that string using a salt only known to your server, then included that has as a hidden var in your HTML.  When the data comes back, do this again to verify the list of urlsafe key-strings has not been tampered with.

Comment: Right, one thing more what if i want to get the node by value and thn want to get the key of that object and get object by key

Comment: @AliSajid, since you have accepted BareNakedCoder's answer and the original question was responded, if you have further doubts please consider asking a new question as a follow-up. Thank you.